# Can I use casting to access multidimensional array by one argument?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, casting

I've a 3D-array and a Point helper class. Can I somehow access a specific cell in the array using only the Point, and not Point.x, Point.y, Point.z?

```
class Point {
    int x, y, z;
    public Point(int _x, int _y, int _z) {
        x = _x; y = _y; z = _z;
    }
}

bool[,,] arr = new bool[10, 10, 10];
Point pt = new Point(5, 5, 5);

// I have to do this:
bool[pt.x, pt.y, pt.z] = true;

// I'd like to do this:
bool[pt] = true;
```

Is there any way I could to that? I know I could use a wrapper around arrays. Is there something I could do with the Point class instead?

Thanks!

Comment: No, there's nothing you can do to the `Point` class to achieve this unfortunately. You can use a wrapper around the array, like you said, or a method which takes a `bool[,,]` and a `Point`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can't do it exactly the way you requested.
However, you could write something which looks just as nice by adding an index operator to `Point`:

```cs
class Point
{
    int x, y, z;
    public Point(int _x, int _y, int _z)
    {
        x = _x; y = _y; z = _z;
    }

    public bool this[bool[,,] arr]
    {
        get { return arr[this.x, this.y, this.z]; }
        set { arr[this.x, this.y, this.z] = value; }
    }
}
```

Which then allows you to assign True in the following way:

```cs
bool[,,] arr = new bool[10, 10, 10];
Point pt = new Point(5, 5, 5);

pt[arr] = true;
```

The only difference is that instead of `arr[pt]`, you have to do `pt[arr]`.

Comment: This is clever. Thanks!

Comment: @Ankhe would you mind clicking the checkmark next to my answer to accept it if this helped you? :)